# How to create json limitation? (Discord)

Tags: python, json

So I have been trying improve my knowledge when it comes to limitation and parsing to json.

I will explain more after the code.

The test data (Two different test data):

```
{
    'sizes': ['EUR 40', 'EUR 40 2/3', 'EUR 41 1/3', 'EUR 42', 'EUR 42 2/3', 'EUR 43 1/3', 'EUR 44'],
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------

{
    'sizes': [{
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176877',
        'size': 'EU 36 - [1]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176878',
        'size': 'EU 36.5 - [1]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176879',
        'size': 'EU 37.5 - [3]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176880',
        'size': 'EU 38 - [6]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176881',
        'size': 'EU 38.5 - [7]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176882',
        'size': 'EU 39 - [8]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176883',
        'size': 'EU 40 - [6]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176884',
        'size': 'EU 40.5 - [5]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176885',
        'size': 'EU 41 - [11]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176886',
        'size': 'EU 42 - [11]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176887',
        'size': 'EU 42.5 - [17]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176888',
        'size': 'EU 43 - [25]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176889',
        'size': 'EU 44 - [27]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176890',
        'size': 'EU 44.5 - [17]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176891',
        'size': 'EU 45 - [24]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176892',
        'size': 'EU 45.5 - [10]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176893',
        'size': 'EU 46 - [26]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176894',
        'size': 'EU 47 - [11]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176895',
        'size': 'EU 47.5 - [9]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176896',
        'size': 'EU 48 - [4]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176897',
        'size': 'EU 48.5 - [3]'
    }, {
        'atc': 'https://test.com&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=176898',
        'size': 'EU 49.5 - [1]'
    }]
}
```

And this is the code I have:

```
try:
    sizes = []
    for size in product.get('sizes'):
        if size.get('atc'):
            sizes.append('<{}|{}>'.format(size.get('atc'), size.get('size')))
        else:
            sizes.append(size.get('size'))

    product['sizes'] = sizes
except Exception:
    pass

sizelist = []
for i in (i for i in product['sizes'] if i not in sizelist):
    sizelist.append(i)

characterCount, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(sizelist):

    if len(item) + characterCount > 900:
        data['attachments'][0]['fields'].append(
            {
                'title': 'Sizes',
                'value': '\n'.join(sizelist[i:j]) if len(sizelist) else '*Sizes not found*',
                'short': True
            }
        )
        characterCount, i = len(item), j
    else:
        characterCount += len(item)

if characterCount:
    data['attachments'][0]['fields'].append(
        {
            'title': 'Sizes',
            'value': '\n'.join(sizelist[i:]) if len(sizelist) else '*Sizes not found*',
            'short': True
        }
    )
```

And here I have 2 different scenarios problem that could happend:

1. Limitation of discord embed is 1028 characters. The means that if one embed ascend over 1028 characters it will not be able to send to discord due to the limitation of discord.
2. Also as you can see there is two different sizes. One that has not ATC and one that has ATC. So the what i'm trying to do create new list with atc and one with without atc (the first try except code)

But however I do not feel comfortable enough with this code because it can still fail if etc a link is superlong and it will always reach over 1028 character which will fail to print out.

So my question is, how can I improve and be sure that I make a "safe" embed post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's take a look piece by peice:

```
try:
    sizes = []
    for size in product.get('sizes'):
        if size.get('atc'):
            sizes.append('<{}|{}>'.format(size.get('atc'), size.get('size')))
        else:
            sizes.append(size.get('size'))

    product['sizes'] = sizes
except Exception:
    pass
```

You don't really have anywhere this can throw exceptions except for `size in product.get`, which can fail to iterate over `None`.

```
product['sizes'] = sizes = []
for size in product.get('sizes', ()):
    sizes.append((size.get('size'), size.get('atc'))
```

---

```
sizelist = []
for i in (i for i in product['sizes'] if i not in sizelist):
    sizelist.append(i)
```

Lets just try to add 'atc' to anything that doesn't have it

```
atc_for_size = {}
for size, atc in sizes:
    atc_for_size.setdefault(size, atc)  # Keeps first found
sizelist = sorted(atc_for_size.items())
```

---

```
characterCount, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(sizelist):

    if len(item) + characterCount > 900:
        data['attachments'][0]['fields'].append(
            {
                'title': 'Sizes',
                'value': '\n'.join(sizelist[i:j]) if len(sizelist) else '*Sizes not found*',
                'short': True
            }
        )
        characterCount, i = len(item), j
    else:
        characterCount += len(item)
if characterCount:
    data['attachments'][0]['fields'].append(
        {
            'title': 'Sizes',
            'value': '\n'.join(sizelist[i:]) if len(sizelist) else '*Sizes not found*',
            'short': True
        }
    )
```

Not obvious what you are trying to do here, you mention in your post that there is a 1028 limit on characters, so you would need to fit as much as you can?

If the 1028 limit is for the entire data object you would need to do some constraint solving, and decide whether you would rather have just the sizes if it doesn't fit, or the sizes + url for as many as you can, or all the sizes, with url for the most likely ones, etc.  There is no generic solution without knowing your desired behavior here.

If you just need to break it up into small enough chunks, then you can keep logic like what you have above, and just check before adding if it would make it too long.

Note that at this point `sizelist` contains `(size, url_or_None)`, rather than the formatted string, so you would need to reintroduce that formatting when you decide whether you want to include the url or not.

Comment: Hello Cireo! I have now read your answer and I cant really understand the function where u do `atc_for_size.setdefault(size, atc)` why do we need to do this if I might ask?

About the limitation is like you mentioned. I would like to fit as much as possible but I think it is superhard to actually do it. Maybe to do a check as you do would be great :D

Comment: Ohhhh I understand what you mean that causes the error. So the problem is that I do have two different sort of formatted string. One with just inside a list while the other one is a list with dict inside it? What if I change the first test data to `[{'sizes': 'EUR 40.5'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 41'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 42'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 42.5'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 43'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 44'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 44.5'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 45'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 45.5'}, {'sizes': 'EUR 46'}]`

Comment: You could do that, but I would do my best to make the data consistent across both, or even combine into one beforehand e.g., just a single `{SIZE: ATC_or_None, ...}` data structure, so you don't need to spend time manipulating it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I will try find my a way to make a check to see if it crosses above 1028 characters or not. Should be easy to go through here! Thanks!

Comment: Good luck, and happy coding